# express.static, pending files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webserver

I'm using express.static to serve many static files:

```
app.use("/assets", express.static(process.cwd() + "/build/assets"));
```

It works correctly most of the time, however in some cases (especially when many files are downloaded at once) it keeps files `pending` for like a minute or two.

I'm using:

```
express: 4.9.5
node: v0.10.31
chrome: 36.0.1985.125 m
```

I've tried to debug it, the issue occurs even when the session is off etc.

The issue doesn't happen when there are only few files served.

Any ideas how can I find the bottleneck?

Comment: Just a heads up: you should probably use `__dirname + "/build/assets"` instead so that the path is always relative to the script instead of relative to wherever you're executing the script from, which may not always be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the files actually eventually get served, the issue cannot be with the code.  Here are a couple places I would suggest you look at to find the problem

- Do you have a lot of files in the '/build/assets/' folder?  This may increase the disk seek time to find the requested file
- Is the disk slow?
- Are there other processes tying up the disk?
- Are there some large files that are taking a long time to serve and hence blocking the requests for the other files